# Subtotals grouped by value using COUNTIF to create ranges for SUMIF, but in a single formula

Tags: excel-formula

***End-goal:*** A column with the subtotals of groups (defined in the below table as all foods listed above Zucchini, incl Zucchini).

***Current attempt:*** create a column to define groups using COUNTIF('count all 'zucchini' thus far'). Then use SUMIF to get the total cost for the current group.

***Problem:*** I don't know how to do this without the COUNTIF column (since SUMIF needs range C:C to be resolved first). I'd like to have it in a single formula. I looked into array formulas but not sure if/how to apply that here.

```
FOOD      COST  COUNTIF(A2:A$2;"Zucchini")  SUMIF(C:C;C2;B:B)
Apple     3     0                           12
Pecan     7     0                           12
Zucchini  2     0                           12
Apple     4     1                           23
Olive     8     1                           23
Pecan     6     1                           23
Zucchini  5     1                           23
Apple     4     2                           16
Olive     9     2                           16
Zucchini  3     2                           16
```

Any ideas on how to solve either the current problem or the end-goal problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the whole column of numbers in the output or would only the total at each `Zucchini` suffice?

Comment: @scott-craner, the subtotal at each Zucchini is actually what I need (but with my current setup, I was going to do that as a last step by wrapping an IF(A2="Zucchini") around everything).

Comment: One note, always ask for what you want in the end.  Getting the end product may be easier than the steps you think should be taken.

Comment: @Scott Craner, agreed, you couldn't be more right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2="Zucchini",SUM($B$1:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

It basically sums everything to the row and subtracts what is already accounted for.

[image]

Comment: Wow. So simple in the end. I really overcomplicated it.. Thank you @Scott-Craner!